# OneLogin OpenId cookie expiration

Tags: openid, onelogin

I have successfully implement OneLogin OpenId Connect SSO and I think it works great with one caviat.

1. When user hits http://localhost/testApp site hosted in local IIS, he is redirected to OneLogin to sign in.
2. Once signed in OneLogin redirects me to the http://localhost/testApp/LoginStep2?code=@@#$@#$@#$@#$@#$
3. Using the code I can retrieve users JWT.
4. At this point user is logged in.

If user open new tab in the same browser and navigates to the app, user will be "auto" logged in because browser has the One Login cookie (correct me on this)

If the user restarts the browser and goes to the http://localhost/testApp, user is required to login yet again...I believe this is due to one login cookies are being deleted when browser closes (new browser session).

Digging deaper, I can achieve functionality I am looking for if I manually modify Expires/Max-Age to be desired date in the future instead of "Session" on `sub_session_onelogin.com` cookie

Is there way to configure expiration of One Login cookies for OpenId flow? I would like user to stay logged in until preset expiration/timeout or explicit Log Out, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the cookies to last longer, you can control this via the user policies in the OneLogin admin.

Since the cookie lifespan controls (to a certain extent) how long the SSO session lasts, it's pretty fundamental to the users' security posture and is under the control of the users' policy.

Comment: Thanks for the direction John. Would you be able to specify which setting exactly controls cookie expiration? I have tried setting Fixed Time and Invactivty to 336 hours (14 days) but that had no affect on cookie expiration => still get it as Session, therefore expires on browser restart. Setting "keep me signed in" and using it during sign in works though

Comment: I have created the policy and associated it with my test user but appears that Session Timeout => Fixed Time or Inactivity don't have affect on cookie expiration

Comment: Or is "Keep me signed in" option is the only way to make cookie survive browser restart, based on my quick testing appears to be the case, please advise

Comment: That's correct - if you want a permanent (not session) cookie, the only way to accomplish that across browser session close is the "keep me signed in" option.

This cookie will only be cleared if you expressly log out.

Answer (score 0):

I believe OneLogin's Cookies are not expired. You are saying this because maybe your app is a test app and it is not checking if its Cookies are present which is understandable.

What you can do to check if OneLogin's Cookies are there is start the flow again from your app and check if OneLogin asks for Credentials. I think it won't ask. OneLogin standard User session lasts for 8 hours.

Let me know if this helps.